# Get Amazon ECS container to exit if Flask Entrypoint fails

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, amazon-ecs

I am updating my ECS service to use a new task definition. The task definition in this case is a flask application running on gunicorn.

Under certain conditions, I want the flask application to exit and subsequently the update to the ECS service to fail. In this case, I want to check the database connection (and exit if the database connection is not running).

However, I am not seeing this. Whenever I exit or kill the flask application (using sys.kill or os.kill for example), the task definitions still continue to be updated.

How do I kill the update to the ECS service as well given that my entrypoint fails?

I saw this as well: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/graceful-shutdowns-with-ecs/ but the SIGTERM also doesn't work.

Comment: I just had some issues with ECS running tasks not getting the proper signals sent from ECS and what solved for me was: make sure your process is the root one started by docker, in other words, if it's started by a bash script you'll have to add signal handling on the bash script to notify your process. Something else that I found was that ECS was sending SIGQUIT and not SIGTERM as documented. So based on that I put traps on various signals just in case on my bash script launcher.

Answer (score 0):

To update this, the problem was that the service kept crash-looping. To resolve this, I used the ECS deployment breaker: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/announcing-amazon-ecs-deployment-circuit-breaker/ which allows you to exit out of this loop.